# how to use whereNull and orwhereBetween in Laravel at the same time?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am building a system where the user enters the date range and gets the data in the form of a table from the database. I have column in database payment_status, value_date, pmt_msg_date, acceptance_date. Now I want to retrieve all the data from the database filter through the date range provided by the user where the payment_status is null. How can I get that?

Here is my Controller

```
function payment_list_table(Request $req) {
    if (session()->has('user')) {
        $data = Doc::whereNull('payment_status')
            ->orwhereBetween('value_date', [$req->from, $req->to])
            ->orwhereBetween('pmt_msg_date', [$req->from, $req->to])
            ->orwhereBetween('acceptance_date', [$req->from, $req->to])
            ->get();
        return view('payment/table_payment_list', ['datas'=>$data,]);
    } else {

    }
}
```

I am able to get all data from that date range along with data having payment status not null. how I can I fix it.

Comment: you mean you want to get those rows only where payment status is `null`??

Comment: $data = Doc::whereNull('payment_status')->where(function ($query)use($req){
        $query->whereBetween('value_date',[$req->from,$req->to])
            $query->orwhereBetween('pmt_msg_date',[$req->from,$req->to])->orwhereBetween('acceptance_date',[$req->from,$req->to]);

    })->get();  is this are you looking for

Comment: Yes....and the date range set by the user received via $req....

Comment: then you have to specify data type of pmt_msg_date or acceptance_date and also format of $req->from,$req->to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use advanced where clause with closure for this.

```
$data = Doc::whereNull('payment_status')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($req) {
            $query->whereBetween('value_date', [$req->from, $req->to])
                ->orWhereBetween('pmt_msg_date', [$req->from, $req->to])
                ->orWhereBetween('acceptance_date', [$req->from, $req->to]);
        })
        ->get();
```